# Search button click on keypress of enter using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have textboxes and each textbox contains search button beside that. 
On Key press i need to validate for alphanumeric characters and if Enter Key is pressed i need to Search.
Right Now, My Textbox contains:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtId" runat="server"  TabIndex="1" MaxLength="30" onkeypress="return validateAlphaNumeric(event, this);"></asp:TextBox>
Search Button:
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgSearch" runat="server" ImgUrl=".gif" OnClientClick="returnpassTxtboxValue(imgSearch);"/>
```

Now if i do:

```
If (event.KeyCode == 13) then SearchButton.Click();
```

This executes the `returnpassTxtboxValue(imgSearch)` function of Search button and then return back to textBox function `validateAlphaNumeric()` of `Textbox`. So my test fails by throwing `parameterCount` exception.

Javascript for textbox:

```
 function validateAlphaNumeric(evt, textBox) {
        var charCode;
        charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : window.event.keyCode;

        if (charCode >= 97 && charCode <= 122 || charCode >= 65 && charCode <= 90 || charCode == 8 || charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57 || charCode == 45 || charCode == 13) {
            //if (charCode == 13) {
            //    document.getElementById('SearchButton').click();

            //}
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Can u pls suggest me how to over come this?

Thanks,

Comment: can add the rest of your codes as well ? like your javascript and code behind

Comment: Javascript for text: added in the above question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this way of implementation

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtId" runat="server"  TabIndex="1" MaxLength="30" onkeypress="return validateAlphaNumeric(event, this);"></asp:TextBox>
    Search Button:
    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgSearch" runat="server" ImgUrl=".gif" onclientClick="Validate(this);"/>


$(document).ready(function(e){
  $("#txtId").on("keyup",function(e){

     if(e.keycode == 13){ 
        $("#imgSearch").trigger("click");
     }
  }  
});

function Validate(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 // Do your validation Code here.
}
```

Thanks

Comment: e.preventDefault() stops my code : 
Below error is showing :
Object doesn't support property or method 'preventDefault'

Comment: Need to add return false after the Search button click in Validation of text box... It worked :) Thanks all :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to write below code on your textbox (txtId) keypress event

```
 if (e.keyCode == 13) $j("#imgSearch").trigger('click');
```

this code execute button (imgSearch) click event on press enter key

```
function validateAlphaNumeric(event, obj)
{
   if (event.keyCode == 13) $j("#imgSearch").trigger('click');
}
```

Comment: Can u pls give me the aboce code in Javascript?
and i think i have done the same thing in javascript.

if(event.keycode == 13){document.getelemntById('imgSearch').Click();

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#txtId").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    $('#btnId').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Search Button:

Please do in following way for a single textbox

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#txtId").keypress(function(e){

if(e.which==10 || e.which==13)
{
$("#imgSearch").click();
}
```

});

});

Answer (score 0):

Need to add Return false.

```
if(event.KeyCode == 13){
document.getElementById('SearchButton').click();
return false;
}
```

It will work...thanks all :)